# How much to cook fennel?

Tags: cooking-time

I would like to prepare a dish with [fennel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fennel) (foeniculum vulgare) as it has blossomed recently. Should I cultivate the leaves, fruits and afterwards the bulb or should I leave the bulb since it is a perennial. Further, how am I to cook and include these or can they be eaten raw?

Comment: Do you have fennel bulbs or just stems etc? There’s a difference between the garden/vegetable kind and the (often wild) kind for seeds.

Comment: [My mum was the horticulturalist, not me, so I might be wrong here] Don't the bulbs 'split' [somehow, by biology or even *magic*, see 'mum disclaimer' above;) so the trick is to use every alternate bulb as a vegetable & leave the ones in between for flowers/fruit/next year?

Comment: I have the crop in entirety. Interesting Tetsujin, thank you for sharing! I am hopeful to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can be eaten both raw and cooked. When preparing raw cut, trim and clean then place in ice water to preserve crispness. Serve immediately after taking out of water. Raw Fennel has a much stronger anise flavor.
My personal favorite is to slice bulb, stems and leaves appx 1cm thick and sautee in olive oil until translucent. It will still be quite crunchy so adjust thickness according to taste. I occasionally add garlic. The anise flavor is much more mild